# override hadoop user logs | queue specific

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop2

I have one hadoop job which is running in cluster of 300 nodes, for my job I have one specific queue in which job will get executed.

Job is running fine over production but it's generating too much log under userlogs folder for particular application id , I have executed hadoop merge command and get file of size of 290 GB.

I can see hadoop logging too much in syslog.

I have some queries over it , if anyone can guide me that would be great help for me -

1)- Logs in syslog is based on input data

2)- Logs in syslog  based on hive query (As I can see all the entries are related to Hadoop processing, I don't think hive query have any impact in over creation of log)

3)- is there any way to reduce info in syslog for any specfic job running in huge cluser with interfering cluster configuration (for other jobs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Logs in hadoop shows data from container allocation by YARN, Mapping, Reducing to the final result written.
2. > Logging during Hive execution on a Hadoop cluster is controlled by
   >   Hadoop configuration. Usually Hadoop will produce one log file per map
   >   and reduce task stored on the cluster machine(s) where the task was
   >   executed. The log files can be obtained by clicking through to the
   >   Task Details page from the Hadoop JobTracker Web UI.

   Refer: [Hive Logging](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted#GettingStarted-HiveLogging)
3. To configure Hadoop logs, refer: [How To Configure-Log4j_Configuration](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowToConfigure#Log4j_Configuration)